# Load controllers in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm working on laravel 5 based app.
I want my pages url to be anything and manage different pages according controllers, which I attach from the cms control panel.
In my routes.php file I have such code

```
Route::get('{slug}/{params?}', 'site\PagesController@getPage')->where('params', '(.*)');
```

My PagesController looks like this

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\site;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Pages;

class PagesController extends Controller {



public function getPage($slug, $params = null)
{

    if($params) 
    {


      // dd($params);
    }

    $page = PAGES::whereSlug('/'.$slug)->first();

    if(count($page)) {
        \App::make('App\Http\Controllers\site\\'.$page->controller)->show($page->id);
    }
    else {
        \App::abort(404);
    }

}
```

}

It's working when I dump data from the called controller method (show), but the method doesn't return the value. For example, if I do dd($item) it shows correct data but return $item doesn't work.
What can be the problem?

Your recommendation about a better solution would be highly  appreciated also :)

Thank you!

Comment: if you're happy with my answer you can accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you should return value :)

```
return \App::make(…);
```

Btw. `\App::abort(404);` can be replaced by alias: `abort(404);`

Comment: And for `\App::make('...')` there's `app('...')` ;)